# How to pass env variable to client side in a nx workspace?

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, next.js, nx.dev

I'm running a nextJS app in a NX workspace and I need to get access to env variables on client side.

**/apps/myproject/.local.env**

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECT=my-super-project
```

**/apps/myproject/next.config.tsx**

```
module.exports = {
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    PROJECT: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECT
  }
}
```

In my nextJS app I'm trying several things:

**/apps/myproject/pages/_app.tsx**

```
import nextConfig from 'next/config'
const { publicRuntimeConfig } = nextConfig()
// ...
console.log(process, publicRuntimeConfig)
```

Running the app via `nx serve myproject` does not give me any output on client, but on server side I do see the `NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECT` value. I'm not quite sure if my next.config.js file is read by nx at all...

Comment: You shouldn't need the extra config in `next.config.js`. Simply having a `.env.local` file with `NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECT` env var should be enough to expose it to the client. Try logging the env var directly `console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECT)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For anyone who is still having this issue.
For loading the env variables in react project, followings are required:

1. Create a `.env` file at application level.
   Example: `apps/myReactApp/.env`
2. Add the variable ther with prefix **NX**
   Example:
   If you can variable called **"APP_NAME"**, then add **"NX_APP_NAME"** in it.
   NX loads only those variables which are prefixed with **"NX"**.

If you want to load different **env** files for different configuration, then you can do it like this:

```
For QA: `npx env-cmd -f apps/web-client/.env.qa nx run web-client:build:qa`,  
For staging: `npx env-cmd -f apps/web-client/.env.staging nx run web-client:build:staging`, 
NOTE: you need to install env-cmd package
```

More about loading environment variable in their [doc](https://nx.dev/guides/environment-variables).

Answer (score 0):

When you are running `npm build` or `npm start`, nx - under the hood gets your environmental variables and writes them into compiled code. Therefore you don't need to have any special logic to access them.

Therefore in your frontend files just access .env through `process.env.SOME_CONST`.

Also, an interesting fact about compiled code is that if you have loggers during debugging like these:

```
if(environment === 'development') {
  console.log('Log sample');
}
```

Then this code is omitted totally from compiled code which shrinks your dist files.

---

This may be useful to you:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

---

Best wishes, Eugene.